# Pandas rolling slope on groupby objects

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I would like to estimate a rolling slope on a grouped dataframe.

Let's say that I have the following df:

```
           Date   tags   weight
22   2004-05-12    a    0.000081
23   2004-05-13    a    0.000073
24   2004-05-14    a    0.000085
25   2004-05-17    a    0.000089
26   2004-05-18    b    0.000034
27   2004-05-19    b    0.000048

......

1000   2004-05-20    b    0.000034
1001   2004-05-21    b    0.000037
1002   2004-05-24    c    0.000043
1003   2004-05-25    c    0.000038
1004   2004-05-26    c    0.000029
```

How could I calculate a rolling slope over 10 dates and for each group?

I tried:

```
from scipy.stats import linregress
df['rolling_slope'] = df.groupby('tags').rolling(window=10,
                               min_periods=2).apply(lambda v: linregress(v.Date, v.weight))
```

but it seems that I can't apply the function to a Series

Comment: I don't think you can regress on `v.tags` which are strings.

Comment: oups sorry, i meant ```v.Date```. Post edited, ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df['rolling_slope'] = (df.groupby('tags')['weight']
   .rolling(window=10, min_period=2)
   .apply(lambda v: linregress(np.arange(len(v)), v).slope )
   .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
)
```

But this is rolling on number of rows only, not really looking back `10 days`. There's also an option `rolling('10D')` but you would need to set `date` as index.

Comment: Thank you, it really helps ! I am also interested by the option of rolling on a fixed window expressed in days. So, I set ```date``` as index and try the option ```rolling('10D')```. However, the results of the linear regressions are different from the first option although in the specific case presented here it should be the same. Should I modify ```np.arange(len(v))``` in the ```linregress``` function?

Comment: Ok sorry, your solution worked also with ```rolling('10D')```. I did not notice that it gives a slope from the second row while the first option gives a slope from the 10th row. Thank you very much, it really helps ! I was in particular looking for a way to roll on a fixed widow expressed in days and not a range.